# UIActionSheet with 2 buttons ....{iPhone SDK}

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiactionsheet

hi iam creating an UIActionSheet  with 2 buttons . now i want two  each buttons do separate work . 
 how can i declare my 2 buttons on the :

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)menu
                didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

i use this code :

```
if (buttonIndex != [menu cancelButtonIndex])    {
    // do somthing
}
```

but it means if user click any button except CANCEL BUTTON do somthing . 
Thank you .

Answer (score 4):

This will work much more generically. You can extend it to as many buttons as you like:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)menu didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            //do something
            break;
        case 1:
            //do something else
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: but have problem ! for example if put an alertview on the case 0 i get some error !!! why ? 
http://freezpic.com/pics/5a582757ae023e8f55dfcbf535fdbaa3.jpg

Comment: You've got an error before you declare the UIAlertView. Check the line above, it might be missing a semicolon or something similar.

Comment: sorry chek the my answer !  why comment doesn't support code tag? 
my code is there

Comment: I think you aren't allowed to open a case with a variable declaration. I don't know why. If I add an NSLog statement in there or even just a semicolon it works fine.

Comment: `case` is a label, and a label can only precede a statement, not a declaration. Declarations aren't statements in C, which means they aren't in Objective-C, either. Put an empty statement (`;`) between the `case` label and declaration, or wrap the whole case in a compound statement (`{` … `}`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I managed to figure it out, but the details are always much more interesting.

Comment: Thank you peter and David . it works great :) i Love stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)menu didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == [menu cancelButtonIndex]) {
        // do something because the user clicked "cancel".
    } else {
        // do something because the user clicked "the other button".
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't any change ! :) what about button 2 ? 
hum ?

Comment: @Momeks: So you mean you have *three* buttons :)

Comment: Dear . i have 3 button for example 
Button 1 / 2 / 3 / Cancel. 
Now what can i do  >?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)menu didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    switch (buttonIndex) {

        case 0:

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" 
message:@"hooo" 
delegate:self
cancelButtonTitle:@"boo"
otherButtonTitles:@"yoo"];

            [alert show];
            [alert release];

            break;
            case 1:
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```